# Has anyone experienced side effects (including performance issue) of using getObjectsUnderPoint?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Before I go making major change in my ongoing game project, I just want to hear from others if anyone has found any issues with getObjectsUnderPoint() function of the DisplayObject?

**Update:**
Not just the performance issue but any other limitations of using it (like it doesn't detect certain type of UIelements (just as example))

I will have three layers in my application (which an Isometric game)

- Background -- This is just a background which stays in the bottom, has nothing to do with game
- Middle Layer -- This is the playable area, Here all my game elements will be placed on this layer
- Top Layer -- This is one dummy transparent layer covers entire playable area which interrupts all the mouse events. This is where I want to use the getObjectsUnderPoint()

So, player wants to click on the element, the top layer will interrupt the mouseevent and then check if there is something placed or just a plain background and take appropriate action like, notify the underneath object.

This really doesn't require to be done this way because I could simply add moues events for all those items placed on the map directly but because I would be using getObjectsUnderPoint() anyway to check if there is anything beneath the item.

If anyone can explain how this function works then it would be little easy for me to make a decision.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, why don't you just stress test the function and verify if it's slow with a number of objects, say, twice as the number that you will have in your game.

Comment: There is a missing point which I wanted to add in the end, updated now

Comment: I write touchlib in last days , use this function for dispatch events and didnt find any issues for few objects . It depends how many objects You have there , You can always kill CPU if You will have too much :] . Maybe You shold make some stress tests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was one annoying problem though. I don't know if they fixed it or not. At least it was there in 10.1 times.

If you have a container and you scaled it `container.getObjectsUnderPoint` will return wrong result. All the time. So everywhere where I needed `getObjectsUnderPoint` I had to call it from `stage` to get proper result.

Comment: I doubt it's returning the wrong values when the container is scaled.  The documentation says "The point parameter is in the coordinate space of the Stage, which may differ from the coordinate space of the display object container (unless the display object container is the Stage). You can use the globalToLocal() and the localToGlobal() methods to convert points between these coordinate spaces."

Comment: If your object was for example doubled in scale, then a point at (3,3) in your container could be (6,6) in stage coordinates.  If your object were to be removed from the stage, then it would be in the coordinate space of an assumed parent, such that if you set the x-position of your object to 5 and left the scale at 2 as in the previous example, then a point at (3,3) inside your container would actually be (2*3+5,3) or (11,3) in stage coordinates.  Anyway, it seems to be functioning fine now.

Comment: There's a bigger problem with getObjectsUnderPoint that I'm beginning to realize though... it's not including container sprites that have children, which could potentially be event targets.  Such container sprites have no graphics of their own, so they don't show up in the returned list.  Despite this, they still technically have area, so that if all the child sprites have mouseEnabled set to false, then the parent will recieve the event... despite this parent not appearing in the list.

Comment: To process getObjectsUnderPoint correctly, you'd not only have to step through each parent of each item in the list, looking for a mouseChildren = false... but after elminating each child based on it having mouseEnabled = false (because the next highest child (not yet the parent) would be the next target candidate.... if you actually eliminate all children based on their mouseEnable property... you'd then have to watch for the parent value changing as you step through the returned array.  At that point, you have to consider the parent of the any previous set of children as the candidate.

Comment: @ValentinSimonov is right about the scaled container. I'm experiencing it right now with latest version of Adobe Air and Flash CC. I've found the only solution is to use `getObjectsUnderPoint()` on the first non scaled container. In my case it was the stage...

Answer (score 1):

It's an incomplete function.  It returns graphical objects under the mouse, NOT all potential mouse targets for event or interaction purposes.  It actually requires complex logic to examine the array returned by getObjectsUnderPoint to determine the mouse target, because the appropriate target (the one Flash would choose if you actually clicked that point) may not be in the list.

First you'd have to examine the object array in reverse, since the items are ordered back to front.  You'd have to examine each object's entire parent chain, looking for a parent with mouseChildren = false that would cause it to intercept the event and become the target.  Whether or not such an object is found, this final object you arrive at must have its mouseEnabled property set to true, otherwise you must skip it and move on to the next object in the array, which would be, for example, the next sprite or shape behind the one you initially checked.  While going through the list, you must notice when the parent changes, at which point you need to assume that all children of that common parent had their mouseEnabled property set to false, in which case the parent would become the next candidate.  This is actually extremely complicated, because you're working backwards in a bottom-up approach with an incomplete set of objects that was generated from the top-down.

To get actual potential mouse event targets, consistent with the default dispatching logic... it is actually easier to start from the stage in a top-down manner and walk backwards through the display hierarchy in a depth-first search, checking mouseChildren to determine whether you need to step into children, and checking mouseEnabled if it's to be a target, otherwise stepping into the container's children and repeating the process from back to front again.  This is much more accurate, complete, and staightforward.  The only problem is you have to code it yourself.